# Does Couchdb support partitioning

Tags: mongodb, couchdb

I am thinking about using couchdb or mongodb for my next project. I know mongodb supports both sharding and replication but I can't find any documentation where it says couchdb supports partitioning. So, do you know if couchdb supports partitioning?

Comment: Sharding is the same as paritioning

Answer (score 3):

CouchDB does not support partitioning, but BigCouch (http://bigcouch.cloudant.com/use) does. BigCouch's partitioning features, among others, will be incorporated into CouchDB over the next few releases, but BigCouch works today.

Comment: BigCouch will at some point be rewritten in Assembler for the efficiency. The web facing layer will be in Pascal, just for laughs.

Answer (score 0):

[CouchBase](http://www.couchbase.com/couchbase-server/overview) also support sharding. Some of it is rewritten in C for the efficiency and SDK are available for various languages. CouchDB supports only REST and client libraries have to use it. Although, I am not convinced to CouchBase philosophy and I place hope to BigCouch.

Note that CouchBase has its own amin app and does not use [futon](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/tour.html#welcome). It is expected, as the engine supports additional services (sharding) -- the feature set is bigger. But futon is useful for developing views (Couch queries). BigCouch and CouchBase are mostly compatible with CouchDB and you should be able do develop using the former. When the time will come to deploy your app and BigCouch patches are not yet in CouchDB, then you can switch to one of the fork :) Mind the minor differences between them: [BigCouch vs. CouchDB](http://bigcouch.cloudant.com/api) and [CouchBase vs. CouchDB](http://www.couchbase.com/couchdb).

Comment: FYI, CouchBase is not compatible with CouchDB. CouchBase was a renaming of Membase while newer versions of CouchBase have replaced Membase's SQLite storage with a modified version of CouchDB. I believe newer versions of Membase plan to expose more of CouchDB's API. Cheers.